# Configure Jenkins to restore DB to a known dataset before running MsTest application

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a MsTest project configured in Jenkins to test a ASP.Net MVC application.
And it's working fine.

What I need to do is, Need to restore a SQL Server database which is located on a different server that use by the MVC application, before I run the MsTest project on Jenkins.

So Can I do it as doing something like adding a step to restore the DB before the test project execution step?

And Is there any way to command (even using some plugins) remote SQL Server to restore a database  through Jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

```
REM restore DB (with REPLACE)

SQLCMD -U user -P password -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "RESTORE DATABASE databasename FROM DISK='path to back file'" WITH REPLACE
```

You need to put this script in a "batch windows cmd" in Jenkins (replace the user, password, databasename, and path to back file with the correct values).